# Safe to change permissions/ACLs for `~/.ssh/known_hosts`?

Tags: macos, permission, ssh

My initial problem: I am using `git` with SSH for authentication. Each time I push/pull, I get `The authenticity of the host […] can’t be established`, and after confirming to trust the host, I can connect successfully, but the confirmation is not recorded: `Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/Users/peterlefanulumsdaine/.ssh/known_hosts).`

The cause appears to be restrictive permissions/access control lists (ACLs) of the file `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, as described e.g. [here](http://backdrift.org/fixing-mac-osx-file-permissions-and-acls-from-the-command-line).

```
peterlefanulumsdaine$ ls -le ~/.ssh/
[…]
-rw-r--r--@ 1 peterlefanulumsdaine  staff  6795 18 Feb  2015 known_hosts
0: group:everyone deny write,delete,append,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
```

and the obvious solution, as suggested at that link, is to clear the ACLs with `sudo chmod -N ~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

However, I am wary of changing permissions without knowing something about the reasons for the existing settings.  So: **why are the default permissions/ACLs for `~/.ssh/known_hosts` restrictive, and is it safe to make them less restrictive by clearing the ACLs?**

(I am on Yosemite, 10.10.5.  I haven’t ever tinkered with `~/.ssh/known_hosts` by hand.  The only tools I directly use that I would guess might have affected it are `ssh`, `git`, and `brew`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly safe. The unix permissions you have set there are enough. I don't have an ACL on my known_hosts file.